# Sequelize Model.increment returns [undefined, number] instead of the affected rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

The problem I am facing is that Sequelize doesn't return the affected rows when calling the Model.increment, it does the change, when I check the database I see that it worked, but I need to know the what are the affected rows.

My code looks like this:

```
// DB file

const SearchModel = sequelize.define(
  "SearchModel",
  {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
    },
    SearchesCounter: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 1,
    },
  },
  { tableName: "SearchHistory" }
);

// then I do the search in another file after exporting sequelize 
  await database.sync();
  const searchModel = database.model("SearchModel");
  let DBResults = await searchModel.increment("SearchesCounter", {
    returning: true,
    where: {
      Name: {
        [Op.or]: searches, // searches is array of strings
      },
    },
  });
```

And instead of getting [Affected_Rows[], number of affected rows] I am getting [undefined, number of affected rows].

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's not your increment.
but your searches...
Instead using Op.or (if you want to use array)
use Op.in

so the code will look like

```
where: {
      Name: {
        [Op.in]: ['a', 'b'], // array of strings
      },
    },
```

or simple version

```
where: {
      Name: ['a', 'b'] // array of key word
    },
```

Comment: Just tried both methods, still the same results